# Отправка сообщений (mail) с localhost

Tags: php, sendmail, localhost

Всем доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как отправка сообщений с localhost. Использую сборку XAMPP (Win7).
Пытался по этой инструкции (http://www.simplecoding.org/php-mail-pod-windows.html) и на этом форуме (https://php.ru/forum/threads/otpravka-pochty-s-lokalxost.40515/) (надеюсь администрация не рассердится за ссылки). Примеры отправки сообщений использую из тех же ссылок приведённых выше. В общем-то никаких ошибок не вываливается, но и сообщения на почту не приходят...
В общем, чтобы много не разглагольствовать:
настройки sendmail.ini:

```
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL
smtp_ssl=auto
; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify
;default_domain=smtp.mail.ru
; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging
error_logfile=error.log
; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging
;debug_logfile=debug.log
; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines
auth_username=моя_почта_mail.ru
auth_password=мой_пароль
; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.
pop3_server=pop.mail.ru
pop3_username=моя_почта_mail.ru
pop3_password=мой_пароль
; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content
force_sender=моя_почта_mail.ru
; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content
force_recipient=
; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required
hostname=mail.ru
```

Настройки в php.ini

```
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like 
Mercury
 SMTP =
;smtp_port = 25 
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = 
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesE:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the E:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="E:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=Off 
; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "E:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой и знает как её решить?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно прочитать ОФИЦИАЛЬНУЮ документацию по XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/faq_windows.html раскрыть пункт: How do I send email with XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать сторонние STMP библиотеки http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись на мою проблему.
Но я походу тупой, так как даже когда я взял пример кода с сайта swiftmailer, мне выдаёт ошибку:
http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0410/72/4a61d99ff600e0eac5aa09a9b76eda72.jpg
Попробовал разные почты (от маил и яндекс), но ошибка остаётся... :(

Comment: Возможно возникновение ошибки, возможно из-за некорректных входных данных (хост, порт, логін, парль)

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку PHPMailer