# Не могу понять ошибку в коде

Tags: php

Здравствуйте,
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что не так в коде:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
    if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];}
    // if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
    if (isset($_POST['form-title'])) {$formData = $_POST['form-title'];}

    $to = "ev.gorelickowa@yandex.ru"; /*Укажите адрес, совей почты*/
    $sendfrom   = "ev.gorelickowa@yandex.ru"; /*Укажите адрес, совей почты*/
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($sendfrom) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $subject = "$formData";
    $message = "$formData
    Имя пославшего: $name
    Телефон: $phone";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo '

<body id="thanks">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="promo">
        <div class="w-center">
            <div class="main">
                <h1 class="title">Спасибо за Ваше обращение!</h1>
                <span class="subtitle">Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.</span>
                <a href="index.html" class="button-yellow" >Вернуться на главную</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/all.scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

    ';
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено! Попробуйте еще раз';
    }
?>
```

Результат получается вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При проверке синтаксиса, находит только ошибку в закрывающем теге, но что тут не так понять не могу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: первый if (request-post) не закрыт. а `?>` в конце вообще не пишите

Comment: Закрыла if убрала закрывающий тег. Результат остался тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых у вас не закрыт if, поставьте в конце скрипта еще одну закрывающую фигурную скобку. Во-вторых вместо `if($send == 'true')` лучше поставить просто `if($send)`. И последнее - сообщение не отправляется потому как у вас не настроен smtp сервер, поэтому функция `mail` возвращает false со всеми вытекающими. Для локальной машины есть ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/651235/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-mail-%D1%81-localhost)
, а так же можно настроить для тестирования по [этой инструкции](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function)

По поводу вывода кусков кода - можно вынести html код из echo в отдельные файлы, например success.html и error.html, тогда ваш вывод примет вид, возможно поможет

```
if($send) {
  readfile('success.html');
} else {
  readfile('error.html');
}
```

Comment: а кто скзал что оно не отправлялось? вопрос был в том, почему пхп код выводится на страницу

Comment: @teran извиняюсь, неверно прочел. Ну я взял код из примера, поправил косячки, сэмулировал на него POST запрос, у меня тупо ошибку вывело, тут уже не в коде дело будет

Comment: Спасибо за быстрые ответы, но, для уточнения: мой вопрос не касался отправки сообщения, меня интересует только ошибка в коде, из-за которой часть кода после else выводится на экран

Comment: @Самаяинтереснаяпрофессия я чуть выше отвечал, что специально запустил ваш код у себя, ничего подобного не наблюдаю. Какая конфигурация сервера у вас?

Comment: В настоящий момент не имею доступа к серверу. Предполагала, что вывод части кода связан именно с ошибкой в синтаксисе. Но если у Вас сам код на сервере работает, тогда снимаю вопрос до проверки через сервер. Спасибо

Comment: у меня такое ощущение что там `?>` перед `} else ...` стоит.

Comment: @teran в том-то и дело, что нету) Любопытно как такое воспроизвести вообще, чтобы понять причину

Comment: @Самаяинтереснаяпрофессия Немного дополнил ответ, проверьте помогает ли

Comment: @СашаБоричевский вы то по чем знаете что там есть а чего нет, если человек написал, что доступа к серверу нет. В вопросе код не с продакшена.

Comment: @teran в вопрос человек скидывает код, на котором появляется ошибка. Это раз. Этот самый код после мелких исправлений нормально работает это два. Человек адекватный пишет на локальной машине и пробует наши предложения, значит и на локальной та же проблема - три. Это явно некоммерческий код, поэтому определение "продакшн" неккоректно - четыре. Я знаю что там, потому как запустил - пять. Прошу без бомбежки и наездов - шесть. Надеюсь, внятно все разжевал?

Comment: ох, слушаюсь и повинуюсь, простите великодушно, коли мой комментарий вызвал столь много стресса. разжевали все прекрасно, все понял, каюсь. не знаю уж как посмел усомнится в правильности представленного кода и ваших корректировках.

Comment: Еще раз благодарю всех, кто отозвался. Перепроверила, установив сервер на локальную машину. Видимая часть кода на сервере ушла, но от страницы thanks все -таки отказалась. Переделала, оставив просто php код для отправки данных формы на почту. После тестирования на хостинге будет ясно видно полностью ли решена проблема.